# Symfony 4 form validation

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using Symfony 4.1 and I've faced up with form validation.
So I can't understand if it is possible to avoid validation of the all entity fields. For example I have a User entity, that looks like this:

```html
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 2,
     *      max = 50,
     *      minMessage = "Your username must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Your username cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
     * )
     */
    private $username;
```

it is ok for registration but not for login.
My login form type :

```html
class UserLoginType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Login page has only username and password fields. But symfony shows an email error when I'm trying to insert data.

[image]

Profiler:
[image]
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using `validation groups` documented here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html

Basically use the annotations to specify different groups for registration and login:

```
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration", "login"})
 * @Assert\Email(groups={"registration"})
 */
private $email;
```

Depending on which fields and when you want to validate.